# Define a time slot in MySQL Database for Booking System

Tags: php, mysql

I was doing Facility Booking Application which allows a user to search for a facility, with given facility type, date, check in and check out time.

For instance: The user search for a badminton court, at 20-08-2016, and the check in time is 18:00 to 20:00 (check out time), the database exists record is from 18:00 to 20:00, it should return "Not available", this working well so far.
But if the check in time is 18:30 and check out time is 19:30, which is between 18:00 and 20:00, it will not display "Not Available".

So my problem is, how to make 18:00 to 20:00 become a slot, and block the time between check in and check out time, to prevent it shows different result.

I tried to include this code inside PHP, but it doesn't work

`if($response["time_in"]<$time_in<$response["time_out"])
    echo "Not Available";
    else if($response["time_in"]<$time_out<$response["time_out"])
    echo "Not Available";`

This is my entire search.php file which use to retrieve data from database

Ps: time_in equivalent to check in time,
    time_out equivalent to check out time

```
?php
$con = mysqli_connect("mysql1.000webhost.com" , "a6539091_UD" , "0108981390" , "a6539091_UD") or die(mysql_error());

$venue = $_POST["Venue"];
$facility = $_POST["Facility"];
$date = $_POST["Date"];
    $time_in = $_POST["Time_in"];
    $time_out = $_POST["Time_out"];

$selectquery = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT * FROM SearchAva WHERE (Venue = ? AND Facility = ? AND Date = ? AND Time_in = ? AND Time_out = ?)");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($selectquery, "sssss", $venue, $facility, $date, $time_in, $time_out);
mysqli_stmt_execute($selectquery);

mysqli_stmt_store_result($selectquery);
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($selectquery, $venue, $facility, $date, $time_in, $time_out);

$response = array();

while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($selectquery)){  
    $response["venue"] = $venue;
    $response["facility"] = $facility;
    $response["date"] = $date;
    $response["time_in"] = $time_in;
    $response["time_out"] = $time_out;
}

if($time_in>$response["time_in"] && $time_in<$response["time_out"])
 echo "Not Available";

    else if($time_out>$response["time_in"]&& $time_out<$response["time_out"])
 echo "Not Available";

echo json_encode($response);

mysqli_stmt_close($selectquery);
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: there is some issue in your while loop. Check your logic

Comment: @DipanwitaKundu but it works well without the two if statement...can you be more specific? thanks =D

Comment: what is the difference between `$time_in` and `$response["time_in"]` As you put the value of $time_in in `$response["time_in"]`

Comment: @DipanwitaKundu $time_in is the variable that get user input, $response["time_in"] is an array that store user input

Comment: but you put ` $response["time_in"] = $time_in;` inside while loop

Comment: @DipanwitaKundu Is because I want to store user inputs into the array.